# grape api with subdomain does not work on my nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, server, ruby-grape

I have `myapp.com` for my main app, and `api.myapp.com` for api. Everything works fine and dandy at local development that's been serve with [pow](http://pow.cx), however when I try to test on my nginx server `api.myapp.com/v1/products/1` gives me a 404. (`api.myapp.com` redirects to `myapp.com` which is expected due to DNS setup)

I'm using, passenger+nginx, rails and grape-api, here are my setup:

routes.rb

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
  mount API::Base, at: '/'
end
```

nginx conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com api.myapp.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /path/to/myapp.com;


        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location /50x.html {
                root html;
        }
}
```

I have CNAME *.myapp pointing to myapp.com.

I'd probably overlooked something that's fairly basic and fundamental, can someone point me to the right direction. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 server blocks..

```
server {
  listen  80 default_server;
  server_name app.com;
  ...
}

server {
  listen  80;
  server_name subdomain.app.com;
  ...
}
```